# Error "no existe en el contexto actual" Visual Studio - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

Aclaro de antemano, no soy un programador ni de lejos; apenas estoy en el primer año de la carrera (Ing. Informática) y estoy indagando por mi cuenta a través de YouTube y algunos foros.

Tengo un problema a la hora de intentar mostrar los datos de una clase a un datagridview dentro de un formulario.  Ya conseguí exitosamente que otros formularios detecten otras clases para ingresar nuevos datos en mi base de datos, pero para lo más sencillo viene y me j*de.

Creé la clase "Show" dentro de una carpeta llamada "Cargar", y el formulario "VerDir" dentro de otra llamada "Administrar".

La codificación de "Show":

```
    internal class Show
{
    public DataTable Seedir()
    {
        Conexion con = new Conexion();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM DIRIGENTE";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con.on());
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        con.off();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

La codificación de "VerDir":

```
using Programa.Cargar
   public partial class VerDir : Form
    {
        public VerDir()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = Seedir();
        }
    }
```

El error que me sale constantemente es que "Seedir" no existe en el contexto actual, pero no entiendo porqué sucede siendo que estoy haciendo petición de un proceso dentro de una clase que está dentro de la carpeta ya citada. Ya probé intentando especificar que es Show.Seedir(), pero me salta "Form.Show(IWin32Window) es método, que no es válido en el contexto indicado"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución temporaria que encontré es crear el método dentro del formulario. Quizá solo así funcione, pero como dije anteriormente, solo soy un curioso, no un fullstack developer.

Al final quedaría más o menos así, para que se puedan guiar los que necesiten:

```
    public partial class VerDir : Form
{
    public VerDir()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tablaver.DataSource = Seedir();
    }
    public DataTable Seedir()
    {
        Conexion con = new Conexion(); "Encendido de la conexión a la BD"
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); "Se puede utilizar otra variable en vez de 'dt'"
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM DIRIGENTE"; 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con.on());  
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        con.off(); "Apagado de la conexión a la BD. Obs: Siempre debe desconectarse antes de hacer algún pedido"
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El inconveniente lo tienes en *VerDir*.

Debes crear una variable de tipo datatable y luego asignarle un valor llamando a la función *SeeDir*.

```
using Programa.Cargar
   public partial class VerDir : Form
    {
        public VerDir()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
            dtt = Seedir();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dtt;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, pero el problema persiste.